# Getting last buy timestamp for msg.sender in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance

I am looking for a way to implement an increased tax fee for `msg.sender` if they sell a smart contract `token` within a certain time frame from the last time they received the `token`.

In Solidity, is it possible to get a `timestamp` from `msg.sender` to the last time they received the token? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a mapping of addresses to the last time they received a token, and then verify against it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract MyToken {
    mapping (address => uint256) lastReceived;
    
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
        uint256 fee = getFee(msg.sender);

        // TODO rest of your transfer implementation
        
        updateLastReceived(_to);
    }
    
    function getFee(address _sender) internal returns (uint256) {
        if (block.timestamp - lastReceived[_sender] < 1 days) {
            // if they received a token in the past 24 hours, set a fee
            return 100;
        }

        return 0;
    }
    
    function updateLastReceived(address _receiver) internal {
        lastReceived[_receiver] = block.timestamp;
    }
}
```